# Displaying A textView

Tags: android, textview

I want to display a certain text  to be displayed when a button is clicked in a new page but the only thing showing up is the default "TextView"

This is the page before the display. so once they click the one button it takes them to the next page showing them there results

public class Option1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.option1);

    Button butn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    butn1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Display.class);

    intent.putExtra("Option", "Choice1");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

once they press the button on the previous page i want it to show what they picked depending on what button was clicked but its not showing they new text in the TextView area

```
public class Display extends Activity implements OnClickListener{



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.display);

    //It works if i just have this part

    //TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    //tv.setText("Exterior" + "\nOption1");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Intent intent = getIntent();
String msg = intent.getStringExtra("Option");

if (msg.contentEquals("Choice1")){

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText("Exterior" + "\nOption1");

}
else if (msg.contentEquals("Choice2")){

}
}
```

}

Comment: What is your issue..? What happened when you execute the above code

Comment: What is not working with this code? LogCat error?

Comment: How can you press a new button on an XML?

Comment: sorry i didn't specify enough, it wont show my message that i want it to just show the default "TextView".

Comment: You might benefit from reading the [android fragment tutorials](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) as this will teach you the best way to do a complex hide-n-show

Comment: Can you post the entire code itself? Because there is no listener added to the button.

Comment: Please elaborate your issues properly. So it becomes easy for you to get reply and for other also to reply.

Comment: i looked at it closer and realized i just missed placed the code. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

You should have the `TextView` be invisible in xml

```
 if (msg.contentEquals("Choice1")){

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tv.setText("Exterior" + "\nOption1 ");

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a certain text on the next page with new xml, send the text as intent.putExtra to the next activity which holds the new xml and there you can display it,within the onCreate method of the new Acivity